# Browsing a complex JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jointjs

first of all, excuse me for my English, I'm French.

I am coming to you because I have a problem. I would like help browsing a complex JSON object with a loop in Javascript (because it generates itself with JOINTJS) but I am not being able to do it. I can do it manually by json [ "cells"] ["7"] ["attrs"] ["text"] ["text"]. Here is an example of JSON for one element:

```
{"cells":[
{
    "type":"basic.Image",
    "position":{
        "x":50,
        "y":350
    },
    "size":
    {
        "width":100,
        "height":50
    },
    "angle":0,
    "id":"4a2802a8-0bd6-4d06-9343-921092a1decd",
    "z":1,
    "attrs":{
        "text":{
            "text":"230004",
            "fill":"black"
        },
        "image":{
            "xlink:href":"/uploads/documents/computer.png",
            "width":100,
            "height":50
        }
    }
}
]}
```

and parse JSON :

[image]

I would get the "text": "230004" (which changes depending on the item).

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: It is `[7]` and not `["7"]`! This is an `array` index and these are `integers`!

Comment: @eisbehr: Technically, [per specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array-exotic-objects), they're strings.

Comment: Really? You can access an array by strings? Wow. Okay, now I have to do some research. Thanks @T.J.Crowder, didn't know that (*and even never tried that*)!

Comment: @eisbehr: Not only *can* you, but theoretically, according to the specification, you *always are*. `a[7]` (theoretically) coerces the 7 to "7" and does a property lookup. More on my blog: [*A myth of arrays*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html). Naturally, if the JavaScript engine has you dealing with a true array under the covers (as it will if it can), it will skip that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the object like this: `obj.cells[7].attrs.text.text`, where `obj` is a variable holding the object.

Also note that as the `cells` property holds an array, you can loop through that array and get each individual value separately, like this:

```js
var obj = {
  "cells": [{
    "type": "basic.Image",
    "position": {
      "x": 50,
      "y": 350
    },
    "size": {
      "width": 100,
      "height": 50
    },
    "angle": 0,
    "id": "4a2802a8-0bd6-4d06-9343-921092a1decd",
    "z": 1,
    "attrs": {
      "text": {
        "text": "230004",
        "fill": "black"
      },
      "image": {
        "xlink:href": "/uploads/documents/computer.png",
        "width": 100,
        "height": 50
      }
    }
  }, {
    "type": "basic.Image",
    "position": {
      "x": 50,
      "y": 350
    },
    "size": {
      "width": 100,
      "height": 50
    },
    "angle": 0,
    "id": "4a2802a8-0bd6-4d06-9343-921092a1decd",
    "z": 1,
    "attrs": {
      "text": {
        "text": "230005",
        "fill": "black"
      },
      "image": {
        "xlink:href": "/uploads/documents/computer.png",
        "width": 100,
        "height": 50
      }
    }
  }, {
    "type": "basic.Image",
    "position": {
      "x": 50,
      "y": 350
    },
    "size": {
      "width": 100,
      "height": 50
    },
    "angle": 0,
    "id": "4a2802a8-0bd6-4d06-9343-921092a1decd",
    "z": 1,
    "attrs": {
      "text": {
        "text": "230006",
        "fill": "black"
      },
      "image": {
        "xlink:href": "/uploads/documents/computer.png",
        "width": 100,
        "height": 50
      }
    }
  }]
}

obj.cells.forEach(function(cell) {
  console.log(cell.attrs.text.text);
});
```

Comment: Oh !! Thank you for your help !! everything is working !
I understood how it works :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help